# psr-2 more then one blank line

Tags: php, psr-2

Is it a valid way(PSR-2) to write code with 2 blank lines in a row?

For example:

```
$a = 1;


$b = 2;
```

Or there always has to be only one blank line beetween **$a** and **$b**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable by the PSR-2 standard.

[The standard indicates:](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

> Blank lines MAY be added to improve readability and to indicate related blocks of code.

Comment: I question how two line breaks makes something more readable than one line break.